# Smart pointers vs. value as member variables

Tags: c++, class, smart-pointers, member

I have a class A which has member variables of types M and N. The lifetimes of those objects are supposed to be limited by the lifetime of A.

I'm considering

```
class A {
    M member1;
    N member2;
}
```

vs.

```
class A {
    std::unique_ptr<M> member1;
    std::unique_ptr<N> member2;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure which is better, since they both accomplish what I want. The lifetime of the members are bound to the object, and I don't need to manually manage memory. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each setup?

Comment: If there is no reason to have a pointer why have a pointer?  All members are "destroyed" in the destructor.

Comment: The only time you *might* want to create `M` and `N` as pointers would be where they are very large, and creating them on the stack could cause you to run out of stack space

Comment: Only use dynamic allocation if you have a reason to, and a good reason. For example, if your member objects are gigantic and might smash the stack. Otherwise, don't pointlessly introduce the overhead of dynamic allocation/indirection.

Comment: Note also that later is not copyable by default, whereas the former is.

Answer (score 6):

use std::unique_ptr if

1. M and N are base classes of polymorphic hierarchies
2. member1 and member2 are optional members which can be nullptr
3. M and N are large enough which cannot be allocated on program stack

Comment: And these are **all** the _rules of thumb_ and occurrence?

Answer (score 4):

Yep, both are correct, but...

In general, there's an extra cost to dynamically allocating the objects vs keeping them as just simple members.   You'd have to pay the edtra overhead of allocating theor memory from  the free store, as opposed to simply using memroy allocated for the A of which they are part. You'd also have an indirect ref  whenever you needed to access them.

You *still* might want to go the smart pointer route if the cost buys you something.  For example :

1. You might want to change the values of member1 or member2 throughout the lifetime of an A object.  The smart pointer method could make that a cheap operation if M and N objects are large.
2. You might want take advantage of polymorphism.  If M or N was a base class, the pointer-based implementation would have the flexibility to use subclasses of M or N.
3. The pointer based implementation could allow you to delay allocating the member1 or member2 until a later, more appropriate, time in the lifecycle of the A.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the size of the types `N` and `M` and how you plan to use `class A`.

1. If types `N` and `M` are small, i.e. one machine word, then having the additional overhead of creating and maintaining pointers is a waste of space and time.
2. If types `N` and `M` are very large and you plan to declare an object of `class A` on stack, then it would be better to use pointers. In this case the large objects of types `N` and `M` will be allocated in the heap area (and most possibly prevent you from debugging very nasty stack overflow problems).
3. If, on the other hand, you plan to dynamically allocate an object of `class A`, then having member variables is sufficient because in this case everything will be allocated in the heap area, and you will also save on the overhead.

Hope this is clear.